# What is the difference between these audio devices (same hardware)?

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth

This is what I see as a choice for audio devices on my Windows 10:

[image]

There are two entries for the same headset (Jabra) and I do not know what I gain or lose by choosing either one.

Interestingly enough, the *Bluetooth & other devices* in *Settings* just show one entry for Jabra:

[image]

Comment: When the mic is in use, the headphone quality has to drop to support two-way transmission. idk the model, or whether it is capable of higher rez with mic & can be circumvented. I'll leave that to someone better-qualified than me ;))

Comment: @Tetsujin: ah! I just checked by playing some musing and switching from "headphones" to "headset" and the difference in quality is stunning from good to worse). Never realized that. Thanks!

Comment: There may also be multiple devices based on driver interfaces like WDM vs MME vs KS, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bluetooth has a limited capacity for moving data between your
computer and your headphones/headset. The main difference between
headphones and headset is that the latter has a microphone, which
causes the Windows driver to work differently
(or there might exist two drivers for all I know).

- **Headphones** - the playback channel uses all available Bluetooth
  capacity to send audio from the computer to the headphones, for
  maximum audio quality.
  If your headset has a microphone, it is disabled.
- **Headset** - this playback channel needs to reserve bandwidth for the audio coming from the microphone, which means that the audio to the headphones has less
  bandwidth available and needs to be more heavily compressed,
  with lower audio quality.

Most phones have Bluetooth chips able to seamlessly switch between
the two profiles depending on whether you're actually using the mic,
so your audio might drop in quality when you have a call coming in.

The Windows Bluetooth Interface requires you to manually
choose in which playback channel your device should work by choosing
between these two modes/devices.

Comment: An important distinction that isn't clear in the answer is "headphones" means HiFi Stereo (no microphone because both channels are in use) and "headset" means LowFi (one channel output + one channel microphone input). The latest Bluetooth version has more bandwidth and allows stereo channels even in headset mode but both devices must support it.